# Power BI Row Level Security using Tabular modelling on premise SQL analysis services

Tags: powerbi, tabular, row-level-security

I am connecting live to a tabular model I created in an on premise SQL server analysis service, When connecting The option to set Row Level Security (RLS) is not available.

I have set up roles in SQL for the requirements I need. How do I make sure this works in Power BI? is there something I need to set up? Is there a way I could test this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can test roles from PowerBi Desktop -> Modeling -> View as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Live Connection, you can create  the "Role" in Tabular,
than you can test it with "Analyze in Excel".

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1200/lesson-11-create-roles?view=asallproducts-allversions

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1200/lesson-12-analyze-in-excel?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.